# How to get path to the current InnoSetup script file?

Tags: inno-setup

How to get path, where the InnoSetup script file you are currently compiling is located ?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you after the 1) location the .iss file at compile time, 2) the location of the final output setup.exe at compile time, or 3) the location of the setup.exe while installing?

Comment: I am after location the .iss file at compile time.

Comment: Get script source path is as easy as `ExpandConstant('{#SourcePath}')`, but script file name... What you gonna do with that information, anyway ?

Comment: @TLama - The question asks the path only. That should answer the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get script source path, use the preprocessor's  predefined variable [`SourcePath`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_predefinedvars.htm). That variable you can expand in your script as an ordinary [`define`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define). In case, the script was not yet been saved, it returns path to `My Documents` directory. Here's just a useless example to test:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{#SourcePath}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);  
end;
```

Don't forget that you have to compile the script (<kbd>CTRL + F9</kbd>) not only run (<kbd>F9</kbd>) to invoke preprocessor to rebuild the script.

Comment: You don't have a "CTRL+F9" key ? Strange :-)

Comment: you are so right and I thank you for your service to our community.  {#SourcePath}\ just worked.  I love it when things just work.